# CSS animation for a short time while scrolling down to go from one section to another

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll, css-transitions

I am a beginner learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I have two codes: the former is HTML, which gives (after compiling) two inter-linked sections, and the latter is CSS infinite animation.

**What I am trying:** While scrolling down to go to section 2 from section 1, in between this, the animation will run for a few seconds, and after that animation will stop, and I will reach section 2. I don't want to change the code of the animation. Is it possible?

*Thanks in advance for helping me.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#section1 {
  height: 600px;
  
}

#section2 {
  height: 600px;
  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="main" id="section1">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
 
  <a href="#section2">Click to go Section 2 </a>
  
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CSS Animation</h1>

<p>The animation-iteration-count property can be set to infinite to let the animation run for ever:</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner things can be overwhelming, don't give up though.

A web-page has 3 components

1. HTML: this is the main data of a document. a browser will render this
2. CSS:  this is styling, it's used to define how things will look
3. Javascript (aka ECMAscript): this your programming tool. Here you can define what needs to happen.

With javascript you can define what needs to happen when someone clicks on the link to 'section2'.

```js
function scrollTo(hash) {
  location.hash = "#" + hash;
  // trigger a second scroll to event, in case the hash was already present in the view
  document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView();
}

function onSectionOneClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // this stops the scrolling from happpening immediatly. But still allows users to interact with the link regulary.
  // add a class to apply the animation. The classname in the css is '.animation' 
  document.getElementById('section1').classList.add("animation");

  // set a function to run after the animation finishes. 4000ms is equal to animation-duration: 4s;
  setTimeout(() => {
    // this callback will run after 4000ms, 
    // we remove the animation class. so the animation stops
    document.getElementById('section1').classList.remove("animation");
    // we trigger a scroll to the other element. 
    scrollTo("section2")
  }, 4000)
}
```

```css
.animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.animation>* {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: green;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#section1 {
  height: 600px;
}

#section2 {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="section1">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>

  <a href="#section2" onclick="onSectionOneClick(event)">Click to go Section 2 </a>

</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have two things to say (these are not clear from my question, I agree). It will be helpful if you edit your code to reflect these changes.

Comment: 1. The above works for one time only, i.e., at the very first it works, then if I scroll back to Section 1 and click on the link again, the animation runs but doesn't go to Section 2. I want this process to be run always.

Comment: 2. While the animation going on, the HTML  of Section 1 always appears, I want to disappear the HTML  of Section 1  while the animation goes on.